# Enqueue Jquery script won't work

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have the following script in the head of my Wordpress theme (I'm building the theme using Underscores) It is used for my tabs and basic query scripts -

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I've managed to enqueue my Font-Awesome and a couple of other bits ok in my functions.php. However when I try to enqueue the Jquery it is not loading and none of the dependant scripts work. Where am I going wrong?

```
wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js', false, '1', false );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not loading (it might just be not working)? Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: Does the code output anything at all? maybe it outputs the URL wrong. Also, make sure there are no other scripts named `jquery` in your `wp_register_script` and `wp_enqueue_script` functions.

Comment: I don't have any other refs to query in the functions. If I put the link ref in the header it all works.
The errors I get in the console are against every script in the page as follows
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `wp_register_script` and `wp_enqueue_script` in a [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) action hook:

From the documentation:

```
function themeslug_enqueue_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js', 'filename.js', false );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeslug_enqueue_style' );
```

Also, try deregistering the default jQuery reference before registering your replacement:

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
```

Comment: Sorry, I already have the correct wraps. I just didn't include them in my code.

Comment: Updated the answer with something else to try! (deregister default script reference)

Answer (score 0):

Sorted! I had my `<?php wp_head(); ?>` below the scripts I was trying to run in my

Moved it to the top and now it loads before all my scripts, pretty obvious really!

Answer (score 0):

I use Underscores for theme development as well.  You don't have to enqueue jquery itself - WP does that for you.  When I need to add jquery-ui for tabs, I do a custom download from the jquery site, paste it into a 'jquery.plugins.js' file within a js folder in my theme, and enqueue it as so:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'YOURTHEMENAME-plugins', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.plugins.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
```

The 'true' at the end of the code bite tells WP that this file is dependent on jquery and loads it after the jquery file.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

for ex.

```
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker' ); when not working.
```

make sure you have enable debug mode. because when php error getting that time wp function will not work.

```
    define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```